# java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier class's method getNumberWaiting() returning random output

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have an example using `java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier` which uses `getNumberWaiting()` method to get the number of parties waiting. This method is producing random results, sometimes it say 0 and sometime it says 1 which does not seem to be correct.

```
package sample;

import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class CyclicBarrierTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, BrokenBarrierException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);

        MyService service_1 = new MyService(barrier, "Service-1");
        MyService service_2 = new MyService(barrier, "Service-2");
        Thread t1 = new Thread(service_1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(service_2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
}

class MyService implements Runnable {

    private CyclicBarrier barrier;

    private String name;

    public MyService(CyclicBarrier barrier, String name) {
        super();
        this.barrier = barrier;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Starting Service : " + name);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Service " + name + " : started");
        try {

            System.out.println("Parties waiting at barrier " + barrier.getNumberWaiting() + " parties");

            barrier.await();
            System.out.println("Breaking barrier for service : " + name);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Successfully done");
    }
}
```

**Actual Result :-**
Starting Service : Service-2
Starting Service : Service-1
Service Service-1 : started
Service Service-2 : started
Parties waiting at barrier 0 parties
Parties waiting at barrier 0 parties
Breaking barrier for service : Service-2
Successfully done
Breaking barrier for service : Service-1
Successfully done

**Expected Result :-**
Starting Service : Service-2
Starting Service : Service-1
Service Service-1 : started
Service Service-2 : started
Parties waiting at barrier 0 parties
Parties waiting at barrier 1 parties
Breaking barrier for service : Service-2
Successfully done
Breaking barrier for service : Service-1
Successfully done

Comment: Could it be that your output line of `Parties waiting ...` of the 2nd thread is happening before the 1st thread actually does the `await()`? Can you change that `5000` to a random or incremental number so that you decrease the likelihood of both outputing exactly at the same time?

Comment: @jbx : thanks for the suggestion. I will try the same

Comment: @jbx : Thanks I tried the same and you were right!! It worked and i was able to see the expected O/P.

Comment: Great. I posted an answer describing why this happens sometimes, if you would like to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Since both threads are identical (including the sleep value), you run the risk of interleaving between the 2 threads in places you might not expect. In this case after the `Parties waiting at barrier...`.

If it happens that both threads have finished that output and not started their `await()` the number will appear 0.

Having a different `sleep()` value for each thread will increase the chances of them not interleaving in this manner, if your intention is just to verify the functionality of the `CyclicBarrier`.

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting this execution order:

1. Thread 1 `  System.out.println("Parties waiting at barrier ...
2. Thread 1 barrier.await();
3. Thread 2 `  System.out.println("Parties waiting at barrier ...
4. Thread 2 barrier.await();

However, this is not guaranteed, it could be:

1. Thread 1 `  System.out.println("Parties waiting at barrier ...
2. Thread 2 `  System.out.println("Parties waiting at barrier ...
3. Thread 1 barrier.await();
4. Thread 2 barrier.await();

Comment: I am not expecting the execution order. I am only concerned about the output of method getNumberWaiting

Comment: @Sammy And you have been given an explanation as to why you get the output you have: Execution of `println` and `barrier.await()` is *not* atomic, hence, the number of waiting threads can change between your call to `getNumberWaiting()` and the actual waiting inside of `barrier.await()`.